# IIS root site settings for httpRedirect and custom error page

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-redirect, custom-error-pages

I am working on the ASP.net web application.

In that, I need to show a custom error page when an exception occurs on the root (Default website) in the IIS.

E.g. 
URLs 
1. http://xzy                   <- This is a root directory 
2. http://xzy/app1/login.aspx   <- Valid URL 
3. http://xzy/app2              <- Invalid URL (No such application hosted)

When I enter 1st and 2nd URL in the browser, it redirects me to the login page because I have set HTTPredirect on the root site as below.

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" destination="http://app1/login.aspx" childOnly="true" exactDestination="true" />
```

This all works fine.

But when I enter an invalid URL, it supposes to show me a custom error page as below settings have been made in the root site as well.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="404.htm" mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>
</system.web>
```

But it redirects me to the login page of app1.

Here, there is no application hosted named app2. So I believe that it should show me 404.htm page but it will redirect me to "http://xzy/app1/login.aspx".

What changes should I apply to prevent redirecting any invalid URL to the login page of the default application?

Below is the full web.config file of the root (Default website) on the IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" destination="http://xyz/app1/login.aspx" childOnly="true" exactDestination="true" />        
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="404.htm" mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: In no case you should use httpRedirect any more. Study URL Rewrite module and write some rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will give it a try